# Case insensitive search with accents

Tags: vim, search, unicode

How can I tell Vim to search for a certain pattern in a case insensitive way taking into account also characters with accents?

For example I would like to have `/ü` match both the capital `U` in `Über` and lowercase `u` in `Grüße`.

Answer (score 2):

Romainl's answer gets you halfway there. If you set `ignorecase`, then case will be ignored.

Do get both `u` and `ū` or the like, you need to use [an equivalence class](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5B%5B%3D). Search for `/[[=u=]]`. This will find `u`, `ú`, `ū`, `ü` etc.

See the manual: [`:help [[=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5B%5B%3D). Further discussion [in this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7394/7933).

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line to your `~/.vimrc` will give you the desired case insensitive behavior by default:

```
set ignorecase
```

It often goes hand-in-hand with this other line that makes the pattern case-sensitive when you use an uppercase character:

```
set smartcase
```

See `:help ignorecase` and `:help smartcase`.

If you don't want to alter the default behavior you can use `\c` to enable case-insensitivity temporarily:

```
/\cu
```

Comment: bonus points for anyone that can tell me how to do collation?  so `/u` finds `ü`?

Comment: @hwjp See my answer below.